# UIDocumentPickerViewController and 'Locations' not showing in mode UIDocumentPickerModeMoveToService

Tags: ios, dropbox, icloud

I have Dropbox installed on my iOS 8.02 iPad.

I want to export files to either Dropbox or iCloud Drive via the UIDocumentPickerViewController.

If I present my controller using mode 'UIDocumentPickerModeMoveToService'

```
                UIDocumentPickerViewController *viewController = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithURL:self.datasource.myFileUrl inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeMoveToService];
                viewController.delegate = self;
                [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

I do not get a Locations nav-bar button and so cannot select DropBox as an alternative location...

[image]

Whereas is I use mode 'UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService' when creating my controller, I do get the Locations menu item...

[image]

According to the Apple docs, there's a subtle difference between the two modes...

> UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService The document picker exports a
>   local file to a destination outside the app’s sandbox.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
>
> UIDocumentPickerModeMoveToService The document picker moves a local
>   file outside the app’s sandbox and provides access to it as an
>   external file.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Which to me, doesn't signal that Locations will be restricted depending on which mode I select.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Also, if there are no apps like Dropox/GDrive installed that support this feature, the button is not visible

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug as it is now working correctly in 8.1